# How to capture filtered values in new array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, filter

I am implementing a "search around me " feature similar to the ones that can be found on google maps. I have an array called "locations" which is populated with values like so :

```
mapPoints(Borough: "Manhattan", Neighborhood: "Battery Park City", Latitude: 40.7117, Longitude: -74.0158),
```

The function "myPlaces()" is where the "search around me" feature is implemented. When the button is pressed "myPlaces()" is fired.Inside of it is 
  func myPlaces(){

```
        for location in locations{


            let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
            let userLat = userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let userLong = userLocation?.coordinate.longitude

            let coordinateOne = CLLocation(latitude: userLat!, longitude: userLong!)
            let coordinateTwo = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

            let distanceFromPoints = coordinateOne.distance(from: coordinateTwo)
            let convertToMiles = distanceFromPoints*0.00062137
            if convertToMiles >= 2 {
                print("It's greater than set amount")
            } else{
                let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
                filteredLocations = locations
                print("amount to come out", filteredLocations.count)
                annotation.title = location.Neighborhood
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
                mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!, zoomLevel: 11, animated: true)

                }
            }
    animateOut()
}
```

The problem now is that I need to take the values that are smaller than 2, and place them in a new array called "filteredLocationsmapPoints" so that I can access them throughout the rest of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
let filteredLocations = locations.filter {
   (location) in 
   let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
   let userLat = userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
   let userLong = userLocation?.coordinate.longitude

   let coordinateOne = CLLocation(latitude: userLat!, longitude: userLong!)
   let coordinateTwo = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

   let distanceFromPoints = coordinateOne.distance(from: coordinateTwo)
   let convertToMiles = distanceFromPoints*0.00062137
   return convertToMiles < 2
}
```

Using filter will build out your array as a single functional operation, rather than an imperative looping approach. This works well since you've already got the logic that identifies the ones you want.

Get your annotations with a map statement, this iterates over a collection to produce another thing.

```
let annotations = filteredLocations.map {
   (location) in
   let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
   annotation.title = location.Neighborhood
   annotation.coordinate = // etc
   return annotation
}
```

You can then simply add the annotations to the map with a for statement (or, I guess within the mapping function if it suits your fancy, but non-functional as that's a "side-effect")

```
for annotation in annotations { 
   mapView.addAnnotation(annotation) 
}

mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!, zoomLevel: 11, animated: true)
```

This also has the benefit of setting the center of the mapview once instead of within the for loop!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How would I be able to add the annotation points that are within the filteredLocations [the portion that comes after the "else" statement in my original function]

Comment: Updated with the annotations!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array at the top of your class call it filteredLocationsmapPoints

```
var filteredLocationsmapPoints = [CGFloat]()
```

Now inside your for loop append the ones which are less than 2

```
for location in locations{


        let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
        let userLat = userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
        let userLong = userLocation?.coordinate.longitude

        let coordinateOne = CLLocation(latitude: userLat!, longitude: userLong!)
        let coordinateTwo = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

        let distanceFromPoints = coordinateOne.distance(from: coordinateTwo)
        let convertToMiles = distanceFromPoints*0.00062137
        if convertToMiles >= 2 {
            print("It's greater than set amount")
        } else{
            // here you append the values which are less than 2
            filteredLocationsmapPoints.append(convertToMiles)

            let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
            filteredLocations = locations
            print("amount to come out", filteredLocations.count)
            annotation.title = location.Neighborhood
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!, zoomLevel: 11, animated: true)

            }
        }
animateOut()
```

}